# How to display an object property in a slickgrid?

Tags: jquery, object, slickgrid

I would like to display a document list with JQuery and SlickGrid.
In my grid, I would like to display the owner's fullname. I can retrieve it with the property "owner" of an object "document" : document.owner.fullname.

I can display simple properties from a document (for example the title : document.title). But how to display object as property ?

The following source code show how I do (and doesn't works...) :

```
var columns = [
    {id:"title", name:"Title", field:"title"},
    {id:"owner.fullname", name:"Owner", field:"owner.fullname"},
];
```

My grid contains :
+-------------------------+
|Title                  | Owner        |
+-------------+-----------+
|doc's title    |               |
+-------------+-----------+

Comment: What does your `data`element look like? How are populating it? Can you post a sample showing how you fill the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you use not a simple property of data entity, you should use a custom formatter.
Something like this:

```
var columns = [
   { id:"title", name:"Title", field:"title"},
   { id:"owner", 
     name:"Owner", 
     field:"owner", 
     formatter: function(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext){ 
       return dataContext.owner.fullName; 
     }
   }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using the below code.

```
var columns = [
   { id:"title", name:"Title", field:"title"},
   { id:"owner", 
     name:"Owner", 
     field:"owner", 
     formatter: function(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext){ 
       return value.fullName; 
     }
   }
];
```